# Broadleaf 5.1.2 integration with Paypal Express Checkout

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I am trying to do a POC on Broadleaf 5.1.2 integration with Paypal Express Checkout. The broadleaf documentation https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/paypal/current/paypal-environment-setup provides easy integration solution with Paypal but only for version 5.0.1 and less. I can't find any relevant documentation/code for blc 5.1.2 either on broadleaf's site, forum or github.

I tried to integrate the provided solution (in the given link above) with BLC's heat clinic demo on version 5.1.2 by configuring the same way I configured the demo 5.0.1. I compiled the "core" module but when I run startsite.bat on windows, I get the following exception:

```
[ERROR] 14:45:33 ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [org.broadleafcommerce.vendor.paypal.web.processor.PayPalExpressCheckoutLinkProce
ributeModifierAttrProcessor.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:180)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:610)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:434)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.extensibility.MergeContextLoader.contextInitialized(MergeContextLoader.java:146)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/thymeleaf/processor/attr/AbstractAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:98)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:597)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getSuperClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:777)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:301)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:189)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:172)
        ... 19 more
Jun 06, 2017 2:45:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.extensibility.MergeContextLoader
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [org.broadleafcommerce.vendor.paypal.web.processor.PayPalExpressCheckoutLinkProce
ributeModifierAttrProcessor.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:180)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:610)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:434)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.extensibility.MergeContextLoader.contextInitialized(MergeContextLoader.java:146)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/thymeleaf/processor/attr/AbstractAttributeModifierAttrProcessor.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:50)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:98)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:102)
        at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:597)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getSuperClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:777)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:301)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:189)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:172)
        ... 19 more

Jun 06, 2017 2:45:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Jun 06, 2017 2:45:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
Jun 06, 2017 2:45:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jun 06, 2017 2:45:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Shutting down log4j
Jun 06, 2017 2:45:33 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jun 06, 2017 2:45:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 06, 2017 2:45:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8443"]
```

Please help me find a way to integrate Paypal with broadleaf commerce 5.1.2.

Comment: @phillipuniverse. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that, we have since-updated the release notes at https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/paypal/current/paypal-environment-setup. They are now current for the 2.7.0-GA version which is compatible with 5.1+.